# How to add an Aspect Ratio constraint in Interface Builder?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard, xcode7

In a blank new project, there is only one view. When I try to set the aspect ratio of my view to 1:1, the option is disabled:

[image]

How can I add an aspect ratio constrain for the view?

Answer (score 0):

The view you see in the hierarchy on the left is your initial root view. You can't resize it or constrain it with a ratio because it's size will be based on the size of the view controller it's in which is usually the size of the device.

You could however add a subview within the root view and constrain that to a 1:1 ratio.